# How to create a 3d surface plot with matplotlib when x and y are stated as 1d arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, surface

I would like to create a 3d surface plot from the arrays x,y,z where len(x) and len(z) = 250 and len(y)= 7

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                   linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

yields me this error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

I tried meshgrid:

```
T,U=np.meshgrid(x,b)
surf = ax.plot_surface(T,U,y, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
                   linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
```

But this yielded: 
ValueError("Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.")

Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: All points are expressed by their x, y, and z values in 3D space. When you don't have a y value for a point, it is a line instead of a point. By any chance, can it be that what you want to accomplish is to replicate the missing y values?

Comment: I think so. When I print the shapes of the arrays: x=(250,), y=(12,) z=(250,12)  But they should all be (250,12) for it to generate the plot? I'm not sure how to do that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand your data to have x and y for each data point. 
This is done by combining `x` and `y` to form an array with the same shape as `z`.

You can do this using [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8])
z = np.random.rand(4, 3) 

# make sure to take a look hat the keyword 
# indexing : {‘xy’, ‘ij’} and check some (x,y,z) pairs
# to make sure that the values are correct 

xv, yv = np.meshgrid(x, y)
print(xv)
print(yv)
print(xv.shape)
print(yv.shape)
print(z.shape)
```